# Does Go have an iterator datatype?

Tags: dictionary, iterator, go, specifications

How do I write Go code that can do something like a map iterator in C++?

```
typedef std::map<std::string, MyStruct> MyMap;
MyMap::iterator it = myMap.find("key");
if(it!=myMap.end()) {
   it->v1 = something;
   it->v2 = something;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over a map with write access to the values?

Comment: There's no iterator datatype in Go and you shouldn't try to *write C++ in Go* and instead think just what you want to do and apply Go's features to the task at hand. That's why lazy1's answer is probably correct, however it's not entirely obvious what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

In go, it is pretty easy to iterate over a map using the range clause.

```
myMap := map[string]int {"one":1, "two":2}

for key, value := range myMap {
  // Do something.
  fmt.Println(key, value)
}
```

Could print

```
one 1
two 2
```

Note that you iterate in an undefined order over a map, as it is backed by a hash table rather than a tree.

The go [language spec](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#For_statements) describes what the range clause returns, and you can see the [effective go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) page for some more examples.

Comment: If it answered your question, please accept it :) (If not, please clarify and I'll try to help!)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to find a key in a map, then use the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

func main() {
    points := make(map[string]*Point)

    p := &Point{1, 1}
    points["one"] = p

    if p1, found := points["one"]; found {
        p1.x = 100
    }

    fmt.Println(p)
}
```